# Como gerar ruído em uma imagem usando python?

Tags: python, imagem

Como gerar um ruído periódico do tipo **Moiré** em uma imagem em níveis de cinza usando Python?

Comment: Esta biblioteca está perto do que você precisa, talvez juntando alguns blocos consiga atingir o resultado do Moiré: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa foi a solução à qual eu cheguei - pode não ser a mais elegante, nem a mais eficiente - mas serviu ao propósito:

```
    from scipy import misc
    import numpy as np
    
    orig = misc.imread('bear_original.jpg')
    sh = orig.shape[0], orig.shape[1]
    noise = np.zeros(sh, dtype='float64')
    
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(0, sh[0]), range(0, sh[1]))
    
    A = 40
    u0 = 45
    v0 = 50
    
    noise += A*np.sin(X*u0 + Y*v0)
    
    A = -18
    u0 = -45
    v0 = 50
    
    noise += A*np.sin(X*u0 + Y*v0)
    
    noiseada = orig+noise
    misc.imsave('bearnoise.jpg', noiseada)
```

[Ruído](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg9nmklyn93vvjz/noise.jpg)

[Ruído aplicado na imagem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/veim6jn6d0kwjwa/noiseada.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

Baseado no conceito de [Moiré da Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) e um pouco de [Geometria Analítica](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17246/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-graph-of-a-function), criei uma pequena rotina para aplicar o efeito em uma imagem sobrepondo-a com ela mesma.

Segue a rotina:

```python
from PIL import Image
import math

def moire(source, target, angle, distance, offsetx = 2, offsety = 2):

    #imagem de entrada
    img = Image.open(source)
    pm = img.load()
    # imagem de saída (usando a mesma para gerar sobreposição)
    imgout = Image.open(source)
    pmout = imgout.load()

    # valores para as transformações    
    cosseno = math.cos(angle)
    seno = math.sin(angle)
    # distância em cada eixo
    dx = distance * cosseno 
    dy = distance * seno

    for x in range(0, img.size[0], offsetx):
        for y in range(0, img.size[1], offsety):
            # calcula coordenada transformada (rotação + deslocamento)
            x2, y2 = dx + math.floor(x * cosseno - y * seno), dy + math.floor(x * seno + y * cosseno)
            # ajusta valores fora da imagem (como se a mesma repetisse infinitamente)
            if x2 < 0:
                x2 = img.size[0] + x2
            elif x2 >= img.size[0]:
                x2 = x2 - img.size[0]
            if y2 < 0:
                y2 = img.size[1] + y2
            elif y2 >= img.size[1]:
                y2 = y2 - img.size[1]
            # desenha ponto transformado 
            pmout[x, y] = pm[x2, y2] 

    # salva a imagem
    imgout.save(target)
```

Note que na primeira linha faço o `import` da biblioteca de imagens **Pillow** (sucessor do PIL).

Em seguida, está a função que recebe os seguintes parâmetros:

1. `source`: imagem de entrada
2. `target`: local onde gravar o resultado
3. `angle`: ângulo do moiré, isto é, o quanto a imagem será rotacionada
4. `distance`: distância do moiré, isto é, o quanto a imagem será deslocada a partir da sua origem em relação ao ângulo informado
5. `offsetx`: a frequência com que os pontos do moiré serão aplicados na coordenada `x`, isto é, o valor `1` indica que todos os pixels serão processados, o valor `2` indica que um pixel sim e outro não e assim por diante.
6. `offsety`: idem ao anterior na coordenada `y`

### Exemplos

Data a imagem:

[image: Imagem original]

#### Exemplo 1

```python
# gira a imagem em 45º e aplica o efeito em todos os pontos
moire(r'linhas.png', r'linhas-output-1.png', math.pi / 4, 0, 1, 1)
```

[image: Rotação em 45º, efeito em todos os pontos]

#### Exemplo 2

```python
# gira 30º, ponto sim, ponto não, e desloca 50 pixels nesse ângulo
moire(r'linhas.png', r'linhas-output-2.png', math.pi / 3, 50, 2, 2)
```

[image: Rotação em 30º, efeito a cada 2 pontos, deslocamento 50 pontos]

#### Exemplo 3

```python
# gira 18º e desenha apenas a cada 5 pontos
moire(r'linhas.png', r'linhas-output-3.png', math.pi / 5, 0, 5, 5)
```

[image: Rotação 18º, desenha apenas a cada 5 pontos]